# new submit button to node form not displayed?

Tags: 7, forms

When i try to add a new node of type article for example i want to add a new submit button with new submit function so i did like this in hook_form_alter :

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  switch ($form_id){
        case "article_node_form" :
            $form['submit_delegate'] = array(
                '#type' => 'submit', // I tried also '#type' => 'button'
                '#value' => t('Delegate'),
                '#submit' => array('MYMODULE_form_submit_article_delegate'),
            );
            dpm($form);
            break;
  }
}
```

this is the dpm result of the new form element :

> submit_delegate (Array, 3 elements)
>
> ## type (String, 6 characters ) button
>
> ## value (String, 8 characters ) Delegate
>
> ## submit (Array, 1 element)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It shouldn't be shown anywhere! You're trying to put your own submit structure inside Drupal form structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be displayed somewhere between the node form elements. May be you didn't notice that. Try appending this form element under actions like this. Then You can see the button along with save and preview button.

```
$form['actions']['submit_delegate'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit', // I tried also '#type' => 'button'
  '#value' => t('Delegate'),
  '#submit' => array('MYMODULE_form_submit_article_delegate'),
);
```

Comment: it not displayed somewhere, i searched for this new element in the form but it's not shown! But good alternative to added to actions array(), it worked, thank!